# Command Line Check if a string variable contains specific text

Tags: command-line, cmd

I'm looping through a list of directory names, and I'm trying to find out if a directory has certain text.

This is my cmd line code:

```
FOR %%a in (%%c) do (
   echo.%%a|findstr /C:"Plugin" >nul 2>&1
     if not errorlevel 1 (
       echo Found
    ) else (
      echo Not found.
    )
   )
```

It actually appears to work, but then after it finishes, it exits with Code 1. I have output window build set to diagnostic, but I don't see any explanation of the error. Looking for a bit of guidance or maybe a better way to do what is essentially `%%a.Contains("Plugin")`.

Comment: set variable=chuck_lori & set findthis=lori & echo %variable% |
 findstr /C:%findthis% & If %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 echo The string %variable% contains %findthis% ---- this will echo: 
chuck_lori
The string chuck_lori contains lori

Comment: So I think my syntax is wrong. Can you show me what it would look like with my variables above. %%a has the directory name strings that I need to check.

Comment: I didn't get why are you using %%a.. shouldn't that be %a% (if variable a is storing the value of each folder one by one in the loop) and %c% is the variable which has list of directories/directory tree. Do a simple check like: set foldername=i_want_to_find_this_folder_name & set find_this_name=folder_name & echo %foldername% | findstr /C:%find_this_name% ... and see what's the %ERRORLEVEL% value is.

Comment: I'm using %%a because that is the variable I declare in the for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop keeps iterating after the folder has been found and that means the `findstr` executed for the last file failed the test and set the errorlevel to 1.

But this code can also fail if no file is present, as the `do` clause will not be executed so the `findstr` will not set the errorlevel.

If the `for` structure is needed (not sure, missing code)

```dos
for %%c in ..... do (
    FOR %%a in (%%c) do (
       echo.%%a|findstr /C:"Plugin" >nul 2>&1
       if not errorlevel 1 (
            echo Found
            exit /b 0
       )
    )
)
echo Not found
exit /b 1
```

or, you can try with

```dos
( >nul 2>&1 dir /s *plugin* ) && echo found || echo not found
```

that will use the `dir` command to check for a matching file (and set the error level if not present) and use the conditional operators to show the text

Comment: I guess exit kills the entire loop. But I will have multiple directories that have "Plugin" in the name and I need to do something with every one of them. Is there a different syntax I can use to do that in my 2nd For Loop?

Comment: So if I don't have the exit in the If Not statement, it works fine as far as getting all the folders I need. But then it exits with error 1 at the very end. Can I stop that somehow?